# Two instance of WebDriver created

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

I am new to Selenium as well as Java. I am trying to implement the POM-PageFactory model. My testng method is launching 2 instances of WebDriver.

I have a BaseClass that hold driver object and an init method responsible for calling the right drive.exe based on browser. The PageClass is the page object repository with few utility methods. The TestClass has the test methods. If I invoke the init method within TestClass my code works fine. However I intend to invoke within the BaseClass. If I do this then 2 instances of driver objects are created. Please see the code below

```
public class BaseClass {
public static WebDriver driver;
public BaseClass() {
    init("chrome");
    //if init is invoked with in TestClass code is fine
            //do not know what to do here if init call is removed
}
public void init(String browser) {
    switch(browser) {// instantiate driver based on browser
    case "chrome": 
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        break;
    }
}
public void navigate(String url) {
   //open website
}
}

 public class PageClass extends BaseClass{
  @FindBy()
  WebElement searchTxtBox;
  //other elements here

  public PageClass() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
  }

  public void enterSearchText(){
      //page specific methods
  }
 }

public class TestClass extends BaseClass {
  PageClass page;

  public TestClass() {
    super();
  }
@BeforeClass
public void launch() {
    // init("chrome"); .....if init() moved to BaseClass
            // then 2 instances of Chrome driver is launched
    page = new PageClass(); 
  }
@Test
public void searchForSomething() 
  {
    navigate("https://google.com");
    page.enterSearchString("Selenium");
    page.clickSearchBtn();
  }
}
```

Comment: I intend to move the responsibility of driver creation to BaseClass. The TestClass should handle only launching url and performing tests only

Comment: The simple way to find this is to add a breakpoint at the start of your test, run it, and then step through line by line. You will then see when the second browser instance is spawned and know where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 instances are created because you invoke `BaseClass` twice.

You see, when using `@BeforeClass` annotation, you are creating an instance of `PageClass` which inherits from `BaseClass`. Because of inheritance, you are calling the constructor of `PageClass` and default constructor of `BaseClass`. In `@BeforeClass` you create the first driver.

Then, in `TestClass` class you create the second instance of a `WebDriver` because TestNG creates an instance of `TestClass` and again - constructor of `TestClass` invokes default constructor in `BaseClass`.

That's why you have 2 instances of `WebDriver`

Answer (score 2):

Your `BaseClass` constructor instantiates the chrome driver. Now both `TestClass` and `PageClass` extend the `BaseClass`. When you instantiate `PageClass`, it calls the parent constructor and creates a chrome driver. It also does the same when your test runner instantiates the `TestClass`.

That is why you are getting two instances of chrome driver.

Don't extend the `TestClass` from `BaseClass` and it will run only one chrome driver.

---

A better way to handle it would be instantiating the web driver in the `@BeforeClass`. And pass the driver to instantiate page classes. Use `WebDriver` as a parameter in the constructor of both `BaseClass` and `PageClass`.

Then cleanup the web driver in `@AfterClass`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!! Is there any advantage to extend BaseClasss to both TestClass and PageClasss? By not extending BaseClass will there be any drawbacks in TestNG like in parallel execution/selenium grid?

Comment: Coming to your suggestion - are you saying that @BeforeClass method be in BaseClass. It would be great if you could provide some more detail